# $or in mongodb compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm trying for mongo db to show me only the pokemons that are Grass or Water trype, but it won't let me filter it.
[$or needs to be an array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg83I.png)

Is there another way to filter an or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it an array using brackets `[]`:

`$or: [{Type_1: "Water"}, {Type_1: "Grass"}]`

[Documentation for $or](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

You don't need the `$eq` unless using a regular expression